# Introductory C++: Separating strings from digits in a file line and summing up those digits

Tags: c++, arrays, file, vector

I am new to C++ and writing a programme that is essentially a grade book, where i am given a file with students and a list of their grades. Here is an example of what a file would look like:

"John Smith 34 29 10 49

Hannah Jones 45 48 34 46"

etc.

All grades are out of 50. I have to create two vectors, one for the names, and one for the sum of each student's scores (their grade percentage). The vectors are sorted by the highest grades. I think I've figured this part out and have created a function for it.

What I *don't* know how to do is add the sum of the scores together. I know that I need to separate the name from the numbers in the file, and then add those numbers together for each line in the file. I just don't know how I would go about doing it. I've attempted some things, but it hasn't worked yet. Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>;
#include <vector>;
#include <fstream>;
#include <string>;
#include <sstream>;
using namespace std; 

void sort_vectors(vector<string>& n, vector<double>& p)
{
// selection sort algorithm 
// sorting the percentages 
for (int i = 0; i < p.size() - 1; i++)
{
    int min = i;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < p.size(); j++)
    {
        if (p[j] < p[min])
        {
            min = j; 
        }
    }
    int temp = p[i];
    string ntemp = n[i];
    p[i] = p[min];
    p[min] = temp; 
    n[i] = n[min];
    n[min] = ntemp; 
    }
}

char percent2grade(double p)
{
    if (p >= 90)
        return 'A';
    else if (90 > p >= 80)
        return 'B';
    else if (80 > p >= 70)
        return 'C';
    else if (70 > p >= 60)
        return 'D';
    else
        return 'E'; 
}

int main()
{
// Ask the user for a filename and open the file in read mode. 
    cout << "Please enter a file name + .txt: ";
    string filename;
    cin >> filename;
    ifstream in_file;
    in_file.open(filename);

//While file DNE
    while (in_file.fail())
    {
    //ask user to enter valid filename until user enters valid filename.
        in_file.clear();
        cout << "This file doesn't exist. Please enter a valid file name + .txt: ";
        cin >> filename;
        in_file.open(filename);
    }
    //Creating a new file
    ofstream out_file;
    out_file.open("output.txt");

    //Creating the vectors and string for reading the file 
    vector<string> students;
    vector<double> grades; 
    string line; 
    //reading the file one line at a time
    while (getline(in_file, line))
    {
        string name; 
        double score; 

    // Splitting the lines between names and grades
    //locate the first digit 
        int i = 0; 
        while (!isdigit(line[i]))
        {
            i++;
        }
        //Locate the end of the name
        int j = i - 1; 
        while (isspace(line[j]))
        {
            j--;
        }
        // Extract name
        name = line.substr(0, j + 1);
        students.push_back(name);

       // Extract grades
       istringstream stream;
       stream.str(line.substr(i));
       // As you can see here, I tried to make an array.
       // It didn't exactly work, but I'll leave it this way for now. 
       const int CAPACITY = 100; 
       double gradesum[CAPACITY];
       for (int k = 0; k < (line.substr(i)).size(); k++)
       {
            stream >> gradesum[k];
            score = gradesum[k]; 
       }
     }

     system("pause");
    return 0; 
 }
```

So, as you can see, I tried to make an array and get all the numbers after the name go into the array. I didn't try adding them together yet, but I wanted to see if when I saw the array, if it would be okay or not. It wasn't okay. It looks really ugly. I'm totally lost, so if someone can help me with this, I'd really appreciate it.

I realise there may be more errors in my code than I anticipated, but I'm trying my best right now! If you see anything else that can be improved upon, please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std; 

void sort_vectors(vector<string>& n, vector<double>& p)
{
// selection sort algorithm 
// sorting the percentages 
for (int i = 0; i < p.size() - 1; i++)
{
    int min = i;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < p.size(); j++)
    {
        if (p[j] < p[min])
        {
            min = j; 
        }
    }
    int temp = p[i];
    string ntemp = n[i];
    p[i] = p[min];
    p[min] = temp; 
    n[i] = n[min];
    n[min] = ntemp; 
    }
}

char percent2grade(double p)
{
    if (p >= 90)
        return 'A';
    else if (90 > p >= 80)
        return 'B';
    else if (80 > p >= 70)
        return 'C';
    else if (70 > p >= 60)
        return 'D';
    else
        return 'E'; 
}

int main()
{
// Ask the user for a filename and open the file in read mode. 
    cout << "Please enter a file name + .txt: ";
    string filename;
    cin >> filename;
    ifstream in_file;
    in_file.open(filename.c_str());

//While file DNE
    while (in_file.fail())
    {
    //ask user to enter valid filename until user enters valid filename.
        in_file.clear();
        cout << "This file doesn't exist. Please enter a valid file name + .txt: ";
        cin >> filename;
        in_file.open(filename.c_str());
    }
    //Creating a new file
    ofstream out_file;
    out_file.open("output.txt");

    //Creating the vectors and string for reading the file 
    vector<string> students;
    vector<double> grades; 
    string line; 
    //reading the file one line at a time
    while (getline(in_file, line))
    {
        string name; 
        double score; 

    // Splitting the lines between names and grades
    //locate the first digit 
        int i = 0; 
        while (!isdigit(line[i]))
        {
            i++;
        }
        //Locate the end of the name
        int j = i - 1; 
        while (isspace(line[j]))
        {
            j--;
        }
        // Extract name
        name = line.substr(0, j + 1);
        students.push_back(name);

       // Extract grades
       istringstream stream;
       stream.str(line.substr(i));

       // This gives you the mean score in percent
       int total=0;
       j=0;
       while(stream>>i){
        total+=i;
        j++;
       }
       score=total*2/j;
     }

     //system("pause");
    return 0; 
 }
```